# Merging excel files to one workbook calculated fields not populating in final workbook output

Tags: python, excel, pandas, formula, glob

I am appending several excel workbooks into 1 workbook. The generated output populates non-calculated fields however columns where data is derived from a formula in the original workbook do not populate. Is there a way to copy the values to the output workbook?

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeRSX.png
Example of one worksheet. I have 500 of these that I want to merge together.

[2]https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbs1i.png
Output workbook showing the empty columns not being populate from the original workbooks. Those fields were calculations (e.g. C2=Max(Sheet1!C2:C100)

Script used to merge all excel files in directory:

```
Import pandas as pd
import glob

all_data = []
for f in glob.glob("/Users/lidia/Desktop/output/*.xlsx"):
    all_data.append(pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name='Sheet2'))
df = pd.concat(all_data, ignore_index=True)

df.to_excel("/Users/lidia/Desktop/output.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: I used the same code and the formula columns appear as values to me in the merged output file. Can you check once again?

Comment: Oh this is strange. I created these excel files with a script I wrote to add new columns with some columns having formulas. When I run this script to merge all those excel files the columns with formulas don't populate. I opened some of them in excel and clicked save. The files I "re-saved" in excel now all columns with formula populate when I merge the files using this script but not the files that I did not open.

Comment: opened a new question since the problem seems to be with the input files and not the script above. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64069965/issues-saving-excel-files-when-adding-columns-with-formula-to-excel-files-using